# Send Push Notifications with Image Payload using Firebase Admin SDK

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

I am trying to send push notifications through the [firebase admin sdk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase-admin), but the image somehow is not displayed in the push notification.

What's weird is that when I use an invalid key in the notifications object (like `image`) I get an error. So I assume I got the right keys specified. Documentation for the Notification can be found [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/firebase-admin.messaging.notification.md).

The following code successfully sends a push notification but there is no image displayed on the users phone:

```js
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const app = admin.initializeApp({...}); // authenticated with credentials json file

await app.messaging().sendMulticast({
  notification: {
    title: "hello User",
    body: "This is a push notification with an image",
    imageUrl: "https://example.com/myPublicImage.png",
  },
  tokens: ["device_token_1", "device_token_2","..."]
});
```

Comment: did you find any solution for that ?

Comment: @ABDERRAHMANE OUALI unfortunately no...

Answer (score 0):

Change imageUrl key to image in notification being sent by Firebase Admin SDK. I checked with imageUrl key, it does not work, rather,
it gives null to remoteMessage.getNotification().getImageUrl() in app.

In node.js server, you can create post request to send the Firebase message using Firebase Admin SDK:

```
Request.post({
"headers": {"Authorization":auth_key_string, "content-type": "application/json" },
"url": "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send",
"body": JSON.stringify({
    "registration_ids" :receiver_token ,
    "notification" : {
        "title": title,
        "body" : message,
        "image":imageUrlVal
        
    }
   })
    }, (error, response, body) => {
       if(error) {
           return console.dir(error);
            }
        console.dir(JSON.parse(body));
   });
```

Now, handle this message from FirebaseActivity in Android App code.

In onMessageReceived method add this lines.

```
if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
        // Since the notification is received directly from
        // FCM, the title and the body can be fetched
        // directly as below.
        Log.d(TAG, "Message Received: " + "YES");
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        try {
            bitmap = getBitmapfromUrl(remoteMessage.getNotification().getImageUrl().toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();        }
        try {
            showNotification(
                    remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle(),
                    remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody(),bitmap  );
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Define getBitmapfromUrl() as below:

```
 public Bitmap getBitmapfromUrl(String imageUrl) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("awesome", "Error in getting notification image: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
        return null;
    }
}
```

showNotification() can be defined as:

```
 public void showNotification(String title,
                             String message, Bitmap bitmap) throws IOException {
    

    Intent intent
            = new Intent(this, NextPageActivity.class);
    // Assign channel ID
    String channel_id = "notification_channel";
    // Here FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP flag is set to clear
    // the activities present in the activity stack,
    // on the top of the Activity that is to be launched
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    // Pass the intent to PendingIntent to start the
    // next Activity
    PendingIntent pendingIntent
            = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            this, 0, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    


    NotificationCompat.Builder builder
            = new NotificationCompat
            .Builder(getApplicationContext(), channel_id)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_icon)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setVibrate(new long[]{1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000})
            .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    // A customized design for the notification can be
    // set only for Android versions 4.1 and above. Thus
    // condition for the same is checked here.
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT
            >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {

        Log.d(TAG, "Higher Version: ");
        builder = builder.setContent(
                getCustomDesign(title, message));
        if (bitmap != null) {
            
            builder.setLargeIcon(bitmap)
            .setStyle(
                    new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle()
                            .bigPicture(bitmap)
                            .bigLargeIcon(null)
                    .setBigContentTitle(title)
                    .setSummaryText(message)
            );
        }
    } // If Android Version is lower than Jelly Beans,
    // customized layout cannot be used and thus the
    // layout is set as follows
    else {
        Log.d(TAG, "Lower Version: ");
        builder = builder.setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(message)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_icon);
    }
    // Create an object of NotificationManager class to
    // notify the
    // user of events that happen in the background.
    NotificationManager notificationManager
            = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(
            Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    // Check if the Android Version is greater than Oreo
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT
            >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel notificationChannel
                = new NotificationChannel(
                channel_id, "web_app",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(
                notificationChannel);
    }

    notificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());

}
```

getCustomDesign() can be defined as:

```
private RemoteViews getCustomDesign(String title,
                                    String message) {
    @SuppressLint("RemoteViewLayout") RemoteViews remoteViews =
            new RemoteViews(getApplicationContext().getPackageName(),
            R.layout.notification);
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.title, title);
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.message, message);
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.note_button, "Reply");
    remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.icon, R.drawable.app_icon);
    //remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.message_image, R.drawable.app_icon);

    return remoteViews;
}
```